# Select rows with identical columns from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with several columns.
I want to select the rows with no `NA`s (as with `complete.cases`)
and all columns identical.
E.g., for

```
> f <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,NA,4),b=c(1,NA,3,40),c=c(1,NA,5,40))
> f
   a  b  c
1  1  1  1
2 NA NA NA
3 NA  3  5
4  4 40 40
```

I want the vector `TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE` selecting just the first row because there all 3 columns are the same and none is `NA`.

I can do

```
Reduce("==",f[complete.cases(f),])
```

but that creates an intermediate data frame which I would love to avoid (to save memory).

Comment: Is your data all numeric?

Comment: You do know that crossposting on SO and Rhelp is considered poor form?

Comment: @DWin: why? is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Read the Rhelp Posting Guide. You've been posting on Rhelp long enough that you should have done so by now.

Comment: @DWin: I don't see anything there about crossposting.

Comment: I give up @Sam Steingold; It's in the Mailing list page. You are not actually transgressing the "letter of the law", ... only its spirit. "Additionally, there are several specific Special Interest Group (=: SIG) mailing lists; however do post to only one list at time ('SIG' or general one), cross-posting is considered to be impolite." I think that admonition is generalizable to SO which didn't exist when that page was written.

Comment: Look up the word "meritricious".

Comment: @DWin: thanks for the new word. I didn't view SO as a variant of a mailing list, the user base appeared to be almost disjoint. Maybe you are right.

Comment: Crossposting is just bad.  Do you expect people to repeat themselves? or copy other people's answers? Are we all supposed to read all sites that you post to? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/170612

Comment: @GSee: I expect people to answer using their preferred venue and the cross-poster to propagate the best answers through all the other venues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
R > index <- apply(f, 1, function(x) all(x==x[1]))
R > index
[1]  TRUE    NA NA FALSE
R > index[is.na(index)] <- FALSE
R > index
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: this seems to work on the toy example, thanks, but it takes forever on the real dataset with 766,950 rows and 2 columns

Comment: If only 2 columns, try `f[,1]==f[,2]` ? Then replace `NA` with `FALSE` ?

Comment: There might be a fast way to do this in `data.table` but I can't figure it out. Tagged as such to attract the `data.table` experts.

Comment: @Michael, Bill Dunlap shows a fast way to do it in base R in the crossposted R-help thread: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-January/345587.html

Answer (score 0):

The best (IMO) solution is from [David Winsemius](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-January/345586.html):

```
which( rowSums(f==f[[1]]) == length(f) )
```

Comment: The solution is fine.  The -1 is for not marking this as community wiki since you're just posting @DWin's answer.

Comment: @GSee: I don't know what "marking this as community wiki" means. how about you do it and I delete my answer?

Comment: edit your answer (click the edit link), then on the right side just under where you enter your answer there is a checkbox that says "community wiki"